# About the Maxwell Construction

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

[From Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx4li.jpg)
I'm reading Griener Walter Niese's book on thermodynamics. In the section about the Maxwell construction, It says: Because the internal energy is a state function, the difference is the same if we integrate it by B->D->F or B->C->D->E->F.(The letters are in the picture)

[image]
And it says both paths have constant temperature. 
 My question is: How can you go along the path BCDEF with constant temperature, if the state changes?

Comment: One cannot go along this path but it is calculated as a VanderWaals isotherm.

Comment: So how is it justified?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I presume your graph represents the usual isotherm picture upon which the Maxwell construction is build. This means that the y-axis is Pressure and x-axis Volume, and the curve represents the state function P(V) with constant temperature T. Then obviously, by construction, the path BCDEF (or any other path on your curve) is at a constant T. The state changes because both P and V change.

The fact that the internal energy is a state function ensures you that the path integral of the change in internal energy does only depend on the initial and final states, and not in the path itself. You could even take a path intergral that is not a isotherm (T changes along the path) and this statement would still be true.

Hope this is of help.